Is there a way to display content from different content types and media items all mixed together in one view?
I am building a website where we want to have a "library" page where people can go and search/filter through most of the pages and media all in one place.
Do y'all know if there is a way to combine multiple different content types and a filtered list of media items all into one view (so they all show up mixed together)?
If it is possible, is it something that could be done with core/contrib modules or would I have to write something custom for that?
Thanks!

If the content/media is linked by entity references, it may be possible to do this with Views and no additional modules.

Sounds like an ideal candidate for search functionality. The core search is fairly basic so I'd recommend investigating the Search API module https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api
That will allow you to create a search server and then integrate the results into a Views page/block

Ooh I will look into that. Thank you!
